# I need to properly remove MemSQL from a node

Tags: singlestore

I think I un-installed MemSQL improperly. One one of my nodes, the memsql service is still running when I do service --status-all. It's gone on all my other nodes but I can't seem to remove it from this one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running MemSQL 4 and using MemSQL Ops to set up your cluster, you can use the `memsql-ops memsql-delete` option to remove one or more MemSQL nodes.

If you did not use MemSQL Ops, you can stop the MemSQL service by going into the MemSQL home directory (usually /var/lib/memsql) and running ./service stop.

If at all possible, I recommend installing a MemSQL cluster with MemSQL Ops. It's the quickest way to get up and running with MemSQL, and the simplest way to manage the distributed MemSQL cluster. Learn more here: http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/setup/setup_onprem/

Comment: I did install with MemSQL Ops. I ran memsql-ops memsql-delete but I think I got impatient and said yes to something I shouldn't have. On the machine in question, the service is stopped. I want to remove the service entirely. I'm trying to get my cluster back to baseline so any further experiments I do I can be sure that something I mess up isn't being caused by a piece of software that was previously installed.

Comment: Ah, you got yourself in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Pressed enter too soon for that last comment...

Anyways, if `memsql-ops` commands still work, try using the `agent-ssh` command to run `memsql-ops memsql-delete` in the other hosts. See http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/ops/cli/AGENT-SSH/ for more information.

Comment: If you've uninstalled `memsql-ops` as well from the primary host, you'll need to ssh into the other machines of your cluster individually. If memsql-ops is still installed in the follower hosts, try running `memsql-ops memsql-uninstall` on each of the other machines. Make sure to run any other commands that memsql-ops says to run. After that, reinstall MemSQL Ops in your primary host and rebuild the cluster.

Comment: Finally, if all else fails, the last resort would be to kill the memsql services forcefully and delete the files. On each host, run something like:
`ps aux | grep memsql | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`
`rm -rf /var/lib/memsql-ops`
After that, reinstall Ops.

Comment: Sorry for being slow. I can't figure out how to get stackoverflow to alert me immediately when someone makes a comment. Anyway, I was able to get into the follower and run memsql-ops uninstall. When I go to check if the service had been deleted, it's still showing up. Man it's persistent. I actually split your command into the kill command and the remove command and got rid of /var/lib/memsql and var/lib/memsql-ops. I ran another service status check and the memsql service is still there even after a few reboots.

Comment: So the process is killed completely but the service is still up? Check the services started up in init.d.

Comment: I'm a Ubuntu n00b so excuse me. I went into the init.d directory. I'm guessing everything in here are the services that get started on boot? I'm not seeing anything MemSQL related.

Comment: So you manually killed the process using `kill -9` and still the memsql service appeared as running? Could you paste the line of the output of service --status-all where it says the memsql service is still running? Also, in Ubuntu the services run at startup are in the /etc/init.d folder. You might see the memsql-ops service there.
In the future, all this can be avoided if you just run `memsql-ops uninstall` on the primary host